# Link error while accessing NSSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, linker

I'm trying to compile a trivial command-line tool with XCode:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //NSSpeechSynthesizer *speeker = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice: nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", [NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices]);

    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

and even thought I'm importing Cocoa.h, I'm getting a link error:

> Undefined symbols:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSSpeechSynthesizer",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-NSSpeechSynthesizer
>   in byc.o ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Anybody knows what's going on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported the header, so compilation worked, but linking failed because you didn't link against a framework that provides NSSpeechSynthesizer. You need to link against either the Application Kit framework (in addition to Foundation) or the Cocoa umbrella framework (instead of Foundation).

Whichever framework you choose, add it to your Linked Frameworks group in your project's group tree (by right-clicking on the group and choosing “Add Existing Framework”), and make sure you also add it to your target.

Comment: Peter, sorry for the silly question, but where should I ad this option? I tried opening the project settings, but couldn't find the appropriate place in the linker section. O:-)

Comment: Never mind, I found it. It was easier than I thought: just adding cocoa.framework to thr "External frameworks and libraries" group.

Comment: BTW, here's how to do it, in case someone else needs this info: http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Linking_Custom_Frameworks_from_your_Xcode_Projects

Comment: Fernando: Oops, sorry. I thought you were using make. I'll edit the answer.